# Type Error in react & react-chartjs2 (Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to ---)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js, react-chartjs

i have use react-chartjs-2 for some bar graph chart
i am creating the onClick function like when we click on specific bar function should work
using same as mention in docs
link https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/docs/working-with-events/

but its showing error in ref
my code

```
import React,{useRef} from "react";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  BarElement,
  Tooltip,
  LinearScale,
  CategoryScale,
  ChartEvent 
} from "chart.js";
import { Bar,getDatasetAtEvent  } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { ChartJSOrUndefined } from "react-chartjs-2/dist/types";

ChartJS.register(BarElement, Tooltip, LinearScale, CategoryScale);
const labels = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "January",
  "February",
  "January",
  "February",
  "January",
  "February",
];



export const options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scales: {
    y: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
};

export const data = {
  labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Dataset 1",
      data: [345, 229, 10, 110, 20, 30, 40, 50],
      backgroundColor: "#3F3E57",
      barThickness: 60,
      borderRadius: 8,
      hoverBackgroundColor:"#0661FF"
    },
  ],
};
const Chart = () => {
   const chartRef = useRef();
   const onClick = (e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLCanvasElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    console.log(getDatasetAtEvent(chartRef.current, e));
   }
  return (
    <div className="chart">
      <div className="chart__title">
        <h4>Montly Revenue</h4>
        <h2>$1500</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="chart__main">
        <Bar options={options} data={data} ref={chartRef} onClick={onClick}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chart;
```

all working fine but showing error in this point
//here

error logs

```
Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Chart<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, (number | ScatterDataPoint | BubbleDataPoint | null)[], unknown>'.
    51 |    const chartRef = useRef();
    52 |    const onClick = (e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLCanvasElement, MouseEvent>) => {
  > 53 |     console.log(getDatasetAtEvent(chartRef.current, e));
       |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    54 |    }
    55 |   return (
    56 |     <div className="chart">
```

i have searched a lot but didn't got similar error

Answer (score 0):

the solution have been found
i genrally use any type in useRef so it can acquire any type of refrences
so the code becomes

```
const chartRef = useRef<any>(); //just use any type here and problem resolved
const onClick = (e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLCanvasElement, MouseEvent>) => {
  console.log(getDatasetAtEvent(chartRef.current, e));
}
```